# What is the name of this twisty, gritty American crime movie?

Tags: identify-this-movie

The film is recent, probably made in the last ten years or so.

The protagonist is a black male, an enforcer-type, working for a criminal organization (Italian-Americans mostly) and the characters include the screwed-up, drug-abusing, partying son of the mob boss, a real worm of a son the protagonist is ordered to clean up after and keep an eye on. The son is among several who are done in.

The movie revolves around the search to discover a turncoat who is setting people up and to discover who within the organization is dealing meth, a crime the leader does not want to be involved in.

The key scene which will help identify this film takes place in a wooded area. The daughter of the crime boss lures a lover to an abandoned school bus in the woods to have sex. The bus is a meth lab rigged with trip wires and explosives, and blows up the lover as the girl darts out the back of the bus.

The final reveal of the movie is the mob boss fingering the main protagonist as the turncoat, proceeding to inflict bloody, brutal torture and death.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably [The Level (2008)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1397506/) - it went straight to video, and it's hard to find any information on it (it also seems to be called [D.O.A (Dead on Arrival)](http://www.moviefone.com/movie/doa-dead-on-arrival/20029055/main)), but [this review](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1397506/reviews-10) contains a few things in common with what you've mentioned

> "...What seems to be a recurring truth within every story told is that [mob boss's son] Al walked into a school bus serving as a meth lab triggering a bomb resulting in an explosion that killed him."

Here's the trailer [*Warning: Violent images*]:

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much.  It's funny how a movie almost no one has ever heard of can stick in one's mind like this one.